# Right join cannot access Row from other table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query = "SELECT `Title`, `Date`, `Url`, `Url_Hash`
    FROM filings
    RIGHT JOIN form_attributes ON 
    filings.Url_Hash=form_attributes.Unique_Hash
    ORDER BY filings.Date ASC

$result = mysqli_query( $mysqli, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):

$title = row['col_name_in_form_attributes']; // undefined index error
```

This is pretty basic but has me stuck. I have 2 tables, filings and form_attributes. I want to access the row names of form_attributes, but get an Undefined index error.

As a workaround, I suppose I could do this with STMT like so:

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result1, $result2, /* etc */);
    $stmt->store_result();
```

However, `bind_result()` is inefficient as I have over a dozen columns. Much easier to use `$row['xyz'];` STMT also does not work with MySQL full text search which I am using. Is there a way to do this with `mysqli_query` or is my SQL incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: Errr, is this as simple as not closing the string placed in `$query`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was forgetting to explicitly call the name of the table plus the column name in my query. Example:

```
`form_attributes`.`Contact_Info`
```

Works now!

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but FWIW, I find this easier to conceptualise...

```
SELECT Title
     , Date
     , Url
     , Url_Hash
  FROM form_attributes a
  LEFT
  JOIN filings f
    ON f.Url_Hash = a.Unique_Hash
 ORDER 
    BY f.Date ASC
```